Is it possible to toggle Blender's built-in Boolean command state temporarily by pushing keyboard shortcut?
Is there any way to toggle blender's Boolean command state while pushing keyboard shortcut? I always enable weight paint tool's Restrict mode but sometimes I need to disable it. I would like to disable weight paint tool's Restrict mode while I keep pushing keyboard shortcut and when I release the key Restrict mode needs to be enabled again. I would like to do something like sculpt tool's temporal smooth brush which is activated when I keep pushing shift key.(default setting of sculpt tool shift key works as sculpt.brush_stroke with Stroke Mode:Smooth)
I assigned 2 custom python script to A key.
this one works when A key is pushed
bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.weight_paint.use_group_restrict = False

And this one works when A key is released
bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.weight_paint.use_group_restrict = True

but it doesn't work always. When I push A key it surely disables Restrict mode but sometimes Blender fails to get key release state and 2nd python script isn't executed. I guess it's because I do weight paint while I keep pushing A key, and this brush stroke thing disrupts Key release event?
If you know much smarter way please tell me.

You may consider assign both keymap to a operator
Since you cannot execute another operator when the built-in operator modal is running, it will fail in some cases,
Success disable and enable: Hold A then hold Left mouse to paint, release left mouse and release A.
Success disable only: Hold A then hold Left mouse to paint, release A then release left mouse.

import bpy

class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "paint.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.weight_paint.use_group_restrict = event.value != "PRESS"
        return {'FINISHED'}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleOperator)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()


it works thank you but like you said releasing A key before releasing Left Click disrupts A key release event. seems I need to use other application like AHK to control Left Click release state.

Yes, there doesn't seem to be an simple way to do this., unless you can rewrite the paint operator: paint.weight_paint

never mind AHK script won't work.  Simply Weight Paint Brush event keeps disrupting A key release event. Thank you for  anyway.
